# ios twitter wrapper

Tags: ios, twitter, wrapper

I need wrapper for work with twitter api in iOS.

Now I have used some tutorial, but I have more bugs and is not compatible with versions of iOS.

Anybody know twitter wrapper the same as facebook api for iOS.

I try to use MGTwitterEngine, but have a problem with iOS 5.0

for iCodeOuth project also have problem with iOS 5.0 (Authorized user return null)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using iOS 5.0 or later, you should look into [Apple's Twitter Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html)

Comment: ok, as I understand for ios 4 I should to use MGTwitterEngine for example and check for version if version 5.0 in this case use standard framework. correct?

Comment: Not a bad idea. Although, unless you really need to support iOS 4, I would say just go with iOS 5 and Apple's Twitter Framework, since it takes some work to get MGTwitterEngine working, since last I checked it wasn't compatible with OAuth and the solutions to make it work with OAuth that are out there are rather kludgey.

Comment: can i test TWTweetComposeViewController on simulator?

Comment: Don't know off the top of my head.  It might be like MFMailComposeViewController where you can compose an email, but not actually send it. Seems like something you could test yourself.